# Tag-it jquery autocomplete plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, tag-it

I have used tag-it jquery plugin to get the autocomplete list in Yii2 framework .When I am typing any word in the text box the autocomplete list is populating. But when I hover mouse on that list or select any word from list, the list disappears. So is there any autocomplete property that needs to be specified?

P.S.: Here arrKeywords is the list of words that will be populated.

```
$('#myTags').tagit
    ({
        allowSpaces: true,
        autocomplete: { autoFocus :true},
        availableTags: arrKeywords
    });
```

Comment: It could be some browser issue, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome and even in mozilla i tried but it's not working

Comment: I've tried tag-it on chrome, it works without the problem you mentioned. There might be some other things which are causing different behavior.

Comment: Is there any property of tag-it which is Yii2 specific because same code is working fine in Yii1 but it's not working in Yii2?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Yii2, i'm .net developer, [You can have a look here](https://github.com/xjflyttp/yii2-tagit-widget)